# "Activate Your Account" message sent when user signs up, then again when admin activates

Tags: emails, registration

It seems strange that this is happening, but our users are being sent the Activate Your Account message first when they initially register (we aren't including the activation link in this email so admin must manually activate)- but then when admin activates, they are sent the same email.

Shouldn't there be a "Your Account Has Been Activated" message available for this instead? Or at least a way to avoid the email being sent twice?

We are using Pro 2.3.2644, and have "Verify Email Addresses" checked under Users > Settings, and a default user group called "Professionals" - everything else is fairly standard setup.

It doesn't look like a "Your Account has been activated" email message is available- could there be a way for us to hack this in until it's available as a setting in admin?

Thanks!

Ryan

Thanks

Comment: What version/build of Craft are you on? Can you describe the user registration workflow and list any user related config settings and settings you might have set?

Comment: I just tested your scenario locally and I'm not able to reproduce.  When the admin activates, no additional email is sent out.  Maybe you've got a plugin listening to `onActivateUser` that's interfering?